# Как подключить сертификат безопасности к внутреннему серверу?

Tags: сервер, http, https

Всем привет! На предприятии есть внутренний сервер с ОС Windows Server 2008 R2 Standart. На этом сервере развернуто веб-приложение, данные с которого нужно передавать в телеграм, но так как телеграм работает только с HTTPS-протоколами, а веб-приложение под обычным HTTP, то передавать данные я не могу. Как подключить на сервер сертификат?